# A scheme for file type extensions for Mako templates in PyCharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, mako

In our company, we use Mako templates to generate a lot of files: HTML, XML, TXT, CSV...

However, it seems it's not easy to configure PyCharm to recognize the file types with embedded Python correctly. As a result, PyCharm is not able to highlight the code and it also does not search ("grep") within these files sometimes.

Two extension -> *File Type* mapping solutions come to mind, none of them solving the problem completely:

- Use `.html`, `.xml`, `.txt`, etc. extensions for the individual files, assign these extensions to the PyCharm **Mako** *File type*. This makes PyCharm recognize (and highlight) the embedded Python, but since all of the file types are merged into a single **Mako** *File Type*, PyCharm becomes confused and does not know how to highlight the HTML/XML markup contained in these files.
- Use the `.mako` extension for files with embedded Python and `.html`, `.xml` extensions for 'plain' files. This way, PyCharm won't know how to highlight the markup contained in files with `.mako` extension.

The best solution would be to create a scheme with `.xml.mako`, `.html.mako`, etc. extension. This will make the intention clear, unfortunately, I didn't find a way how to configure such a scheme in PyCharm.

Any suggestions are welcome.